# What is the best possible way to create CHECK_FOR_UPDATE mechanism for NON PLAY STORE APP

Tags: java, android, ios, mobile

Please suggest best possible way create check for update mechanism for non play store application.
FYI - Mechanism needs to be implemented for more than 40 applications, currently each application is calling update check api separately which needs to be avoided in order to reduce server usage.

These application also having a parent Application (Like play store), which keeps the list of application but data doesn't update unless you open the parent application.

Comment: You should describe in detail how each mobile app is checking for update from the server side. If each call hits a database, that is expense. If the check is a static file, what is cache lifetime, how often are the mobile apps checking?

Comment: how often are the mobile apps checking? -> On every Background to foreground scenario. (These applications are having more than 4Lakh users who are using it more than 20 times a day or even more)